# QTcpServer POST multipart/form-data проблемы

Tags: c++, qt5

Не могу найти как обрабатывать сигналы POST в QTcpServer. 
На сервер посылаются данные в следующем виде

```
curl -F "image=@/PATH/*txt" localhost:PORT
curl -F "image=@/PATH/*txt" -F "image=@/PATH/*png localhost:PORT
```

На сервер приходят данные и слот `QTcpSocket::readyRead` вызывается дважды для каждого вызова curl. В первом приходит шапка примерно в таком виде:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:PORT
User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
Accept: /
Content-Length: 35297
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------cedafef30775ef86
Expect: 100-continue
```

Дальше приходят данные вторым вызовом `QTcpSocket::readyRead`
Выглядят так:

```
--------------------------cedafef30775ef86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="20uVlYSnKOU.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\  <-- Тут очень много текста
```

Как правильно принимать такие данные? Писать в отдельный файл? или в `QByteArray::append()`? Как дальше правильно достать вложенные файлы в QByteArray? В гугле в основном все проблемы с отправкой POST, а не с приемом.

Буду очень признателен за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `QTcpSocket::readyRead` может срабатывать и большее количество раз, все зависит от размера и количества файлов, которые Вы отправляете.

Алгоритм действий примерно такой:

- Считываем все заголовки, пока не встретится пустая строка - признак того, что заголовки закончились.
- Ищем заголовок `Content-Length` из которого узнаем размер передаваемых данных.
- Считаем все новые данные, в QByteArray, пока там не наберется число из `Content-Length`.
- Далее уже каким-то парсером извлекаем имя файла, тип данных. Еще иногда есть поле `ContentEncoding` которые сообщает в каком формате был передан файл.

Тут стоит заметить, что данный подход будет нормально работать, если передаете маленькие файлы. Если нужно прогонять файлы > 50 мбайт. То лучше сразу файл кусками сохранять на диск.

Я долго искал подходящий парсер, в итоге пришлось написать самому.